# How to count string properties on imported json in angular2

Tags: json, angular

Simplest way to count a specific property on imported json? I'm trying to get a count of status "success" Tried pipes and I'm very confused

```
myjson: {
    company1 : {
        status : "success",
    },
  company2 : {
    status : "failure",
  },
  company1 : {
    status : "success",
  },    
}
```

Comment: Can be a typo, but this is not valid JSON, object cannot contain the same property (named company1) twice

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what exact properties (company1, company2, ...) your JSON can contain, you need firstly to extract them.

Since objects in javascript can be accessed in similar manners like arrays, you can easy iterate all properties with `for (var property in myjson)` and access its values like `myjson[property]`

Try something like this:

```
var myjson = {
    company1: { status: "success", },
    company2: { status: "failure", },
    company3: { status: "success", },
};

var count = 0;

for (var property in myjson)
{
    if (myjson.hasOwnProperty(property) && myjson[property].status == "success")
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

For more information about iterating object of unknown structure, check this post [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an old fashioned object iteration, but I don't know how to deal with duplicate keys like in your code.

```
var companies = {
  company1: {
    status: "success",
  },
  company2: {
    status: "failure",
  },
  company3: {
    status: "success",
  }
}

var successCount = 0;

for (var company in companies) {
  var company = companies[company];
  for (var status in company) {
    if(company[status] === 'success') {
        successCount++;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('success').innerHTML = successCount;
```

**See example**
https://jsfiddle.net/rogtao73/